# Changing the projected value with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How to change the projected value from select in MySQL? Is it possible with the following SQL?

```
SELECT IF(situation=0,1,0) FROM users;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by projected value? What database are you using?

Comment: @Marcelo I'm using MySQL. This SQL is only a sample, but it specifies what I need. For example, if situation is 0 put 1 in the ResultSet, else put 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`CASE` Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html).

```
SELECT CASE situation
        WHEN 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END CASE
FROM users;
```

HQL also has the `CASE` expression. Check [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Comment: This is not a named query but a native query. I will find something like that to named query with hibernate. I will edit the question according the answers. Thanks

Comment: @adelarsq HQL has a CASE expression too.

Answer (score 1):

This depends highly on the DBMS.

You can use Oracle `NVL` or `CASE` as Marcelo suggests.

But I would go for a `COALESCE` SQL function.

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-coalesce.html